# How does re.match().groups() work?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to strip a selection of information from a string using re.match().groups():

```
s = "javascript:Add2ShopCart(document.OrderItemAddForm,%20'85575',%20'Mortein%20Mouse%20Trap%201%20pack',%20'',%20'$4.87');"
```

The result I want is:

```
("Mortein%20Mouse%20Trap%201%20pack", "4.87")
```

So I have been trying:

```
re.match(r"(SEPARATOR)(SEPARATOR)", s).groups() #i.e.:
re.match(r"(\',%20\')(\$)", s).groups()
```

I have tried looking at the [re documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), but as my regexing skills are so sub-par it's not helping me much.

More sample input:

```
javascript:Add2ShopCart(document.OrderItemAddForm,%20'85575',%20'Mortein%20Mouse%20Trap%201%20pack',%20'',%20'$4.87');

javascript:Add2ShopCart(document.OrderItemAddForm_0,%20'85575',%20'Mortein%20Mouse%20Trap%201%20pack',%20'',%20'$4.87');

javascript:Add2ShopCart(document.OrderItemAddForm,%20'8234551',%20'Mortein%20Naturgard%20Fly%20Spray%20Eucalyptus%20320g',%20'',%20'$7.58');

javascript:Add2ShopCart(document.OrderItemAddForm,%20'4204369',%20'Mortein%20Naturgard%20Insect%20Killer%20Automatic%20Outdoor%20Refill%20152g',%20'',%20'$15.18');

javascript:Add2ShopCart(document.OrderItemAddForm_0,%20'4204369',%20'Mortein%20Naturgard%20Insect%20Killer%20Automatic%20Outdoor%20Refill%20152g',%20'',%20'$15.18');

javascript:Add2ShopCart(document.OrderItemAddForm,%20'4220523',%20'Mortein%20Naturgard%20Outdoor%20Automatic%20Prime%201%20pack',%20'',%20'$32.54');
```

Comment: There is no parentheses right before `Moretein` .. do you have more example inputs and outputs?

Comment: @ExplosionPills i'll add some more now

Comment: What do you *think* your regex does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.findall(r"""
   '          #apostrophe before the string Mortein
   (          #start capture
   Mortein.*? #the string Moretein plus everything until...
   )          #end capture
   '          #...another apostrophe
   .*         #zero or more characters
   \$         #the literal dollar sign
   (          #start capture
   .*?        #zero or more characters until...
   )          #end capture
   '          #an apostrophe""", s, re.X)
```

This will return an array with the `Mortein` and `$` amounts as a tuple.  You can also use:

```
re.search(r"'(Mortein.*?)'.*\$(.*?)'", s)
```

This returns a match.  `.group(1)` is `Moretein` and `.group(2)` is `$`.   `.group(0)` is the entire string that was matched.

Comment: Thanks, there are many product names so i removed "Mortein" but added an extra ,%20 before the first (   - works great thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
javascript:Add2ShopCart.*?,.*?,%20'(.*?)'.*?\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Group 1,2 captures what you want.

Answer (score 0):

not a regex one shot, hope it helps:

```
In [16]: s="""s = javascript:Add2ShopCart(document.OrderItemAddForm,%20'85575',%20'Mortein%20Mouse%20Trap%201%20pack',%20'',%20'$4.87');"""

In [17]: arr=s.split("',%20'")

In [18]: arr[1]
Out[18]: 'Mortein%20Mouse%20Trap%201%20pack'

In [19]: re.findall("(?<=\$)[^']*",arr[3])
Out[19]: ['4.87']
```